# JAVA - How can i build my maze shape?

Tags: java, maze

i have a little problem, i try build only the contour of a maze like this:

[Maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiGdS.png)

But i get this:

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEdBo.png)

I think its because of my method print, i didnt put "ln" in my last for loop, because if not the dash will go under.

But i want close the wall of the maze and i dont know how to put dash from bottom to up.

Here my code:

```
private int hauteur;

    private int largeur;
    private static final int LMURET = 8;
    private static final int HMURET = 4;
    private char[][] dessinLaby;

public void dessineMurdEnceinte()
    {   
        for(int j=0; j<(this.largeur*LMURET+1); j++)
        {
            System.out.print(this.dessinLaby[0][j] = '-');
        }

        for(int i=0; i<(this.hauteur*HMURET+1); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(this.dessinLaby[i][0] = '|');
        }

        for(int j=0; j<(this.largeur*LMURET+1); j++)
        {
            System.out.print(this.dessinLaby[(this.hauteur*HMURET+1)-1][j] = '-');
        }

        for(int i=0; i<(this.hauteur*HMURET+1); i++)
        {
            System.out.print((this.dessinLaby[i][(this.largeur*LMURET+1)-1] = '|'));
        }
    }
```

Please your advices, i appreciate.

Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you arent able to close the wall of the maze because you've already added a new line to your maze. You should add another for loop inside your second loop so its like this.

```
for(int i=0; i<(this.hauteur*HMURET+1); i++)
    {
    System.out.print("|");
    for(int j=0; j<(this.largeur*LMURET+1)-2; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
        System.out.println(this.dessinLaby[i][0] = '|');
    }
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept this answer if it is the correct one (by hitting the green check mark)

Comment: Done but i have another question please

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831960/java-how-to-create-my-exits-maze